# the usage of grep --include option?

Tags: include, grep

I want to find all occurrences of `ncread` in every .m files under the current directory and its sub-directories. And I use the following command:

```
grep -R --include="\.m" ncread .
```

But the command returns nothings. The manpage of grep said that:

```
--include=GLOB
  Search only files whose basename matches GLOB
```

Why it does not work ? Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<strike>Because the basename of, say, `foobar.m` is `foobar`.</strike>

Use find and grep like so:

```
find -name "*.m" | xargs grep "ncread"
```

or if you happen to have whitespace in your filenames:

```
find -name "*.m" -print0 | xargs -0 grep "ncread"
```

**Edit:**
Here's how to do it with grep:

```
grep -R --include='*.m' ncread .
```

Comment: really? `basename foobar.m` returns foobar.m

Comment: oh indeed, I guess I made a fool of myself :)
I'm gonna have a peek at the source code.

Comment: @yorua007 see my polished answer, in essence grep's file matchers need matches and not partial matches.

Comment: @hroptatyr the essense is that it requires glob and not a regex ;)

Comment: no it's about partial matches. `'\.m'` is perfectly glob and expands to exactly `'.m'`

Comment: @hroptatyr yes, but `abc` matches against `a` regexp, but not does not match against `a` glob (since `a` glob means exactly this: `a` character, so you have to tweak it as `*a*` to match). And when you use `.m` glob in `--include` this means a file with the name `.m`. Regexes and globs have different semantics, and the misunderstanding here lies not in grep itself, but in the difference between globs and regexes, which I call the "essence" :)

Comment: hehe, well yes, I think you and I are just saying the same thing, I just called the difference match and partial match.  Thought you meant the `\.` which is typically found in regexps. :)

Answer (score 5):

glob is not a regexp, therefore you need to use glob syntax instead of regex syntax: `--include='*.m'`  (note single quotes: you'd like to escape the glob to avoid expansion by your shell)

Glob characters summary:

```
* - any number of any characters
? - any single character
[abc] - single 'a', 'b' or 'c' character
\ - escaping, e.g. \* = single '*' character
```

You can start reading about glob here, if you need more details: [Wiki page about glob](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29)

Answer (score 2):

In case anybody is still interested, --include was broken in grep version 2.10 on my ubuntu precise and I fixed it by downloading a new version of grep (2.14) from the GNU site http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/#TOCdownloading and compiling it from source.

```
-download the archive called grep-2.14.tar.xz
-unpack it: xz -d grep-2.14.tar.xz
-untar it: tar -xf grep-2.14.tar
-remove the garbage: rm grep-2.14.tar
-go to its directory: cd grep-2.14
-do: ./configure
-then: make
-and finally: sudo make install
```

Now run grep --version to make sure you have 2.14 installed now.
If it still reports the old version, try closing the terminal window and opening a new one.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
grep -R --include="\\.m" ncread *
```

The grep manpage says the include pattern is a GLOB, but at least on my cygwin system, I have confirmed experimentally that it's actually a regular expression.